# $\Delta u=\sin(u)$ implies $u$ smooth for weak solution $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-operators

> Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain, $\partial\Omega\in C^\infty$. Let $\Delta$ be the standard Laplacian. Suppose $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ is a weak solution to $$\begin{cases}\Delta u=\sin(u)&\text{in }\Omega\\\quad u=0&\text{on }\partial\Omega.\end{cases}$$ Prove that $u\in C^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$.

I wanted to use the standard elliptic regularity theory. Since $\sin(u)\in L^\infty$, we see immediately that $u\in H^2(\Omega)$. Similarly, since $D(\sin(u))=\cos(u)Du$, we have $u\in H^3(\Omega)$. But then comes the trouble. $$D^2(\sin(u))=-\sin(u)|Du|^2+\cos(u)D^2u.$$ If $u\in H^3(\Omega)$ (which is all we have at present), then the best we can say is that $Du\in H^2(\Omega)$, so by Sobolev embedding $Du\in L^{\frac{2n}{n-4}}(\Omega)$ (supposing $n\geq5$, say). However, this does not imply $|Du|^2\in L^2(\Omega)$ if $\frac{n}{n-4}\leq2$, or $n\geq8$. Thus if $n$ is large we cannot proceed.

So how should we prove this?

By the way, do not use any potential theory for the Laplacian. The original problem was about a general uniformly elliptic operator with $C^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$-coefficients, and here I use $\Delta$ for simplicity.

Comment: You could try to use $L^p$ theory instead just $L^2$ theory. Your right-hand side $D^2(\sin(u))$ may not belong to $L^2$, but it does belong to some $L^p$ space (with $p$ depending on $n$). Hence $u\in W^{4,p}$. Boot-strapping from there might get you into $C^\infty$.

Comment: @StarBug Thanks for your suggestion, but this is actually a problem from our final (which just finished several hours ago, and I really want to know how to solve it), and our course didn't say anything about $L^p$-theory...